# jQuery and Yahoo API parse error / unexpected token

Tags: jquery, yahoo-api

this is my simple function

```
function searchCity(val) { 

    vurl= "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=" + val + "&flags=J&appid=[my app id here]&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(vurl, function(data){ 
   console.log(data);
    });

}
```

as you see is pretty simple... but i always receive an error in my console that reads

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   :

i never had problem with google apis...do Yahoo require some of their libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parser is choking... perhaps the result from Yahoo isn't formatted as JSON? See if there is a parameter in the URL that specifies a JSON result.

Comment: yes flags=J means JSON, it's absurd eeven in their forum no one answered to a question like mine...there is someone usign their apis??